# Display 'PRI' and 'NI' via 'top -stats'

Tags: bash, osx, top

I'm trying to create a script that prints `top` stat for some specific fields (e.g. `pid, command, priority, nice value`). I can print most of them by using `-stats` option, but there is no arg for `ni` and `pri` there...
I know, that's possible to get if i use `ps`, but what about `top`?

Comment: I'm confused, my `top` doesn't have a `-stats` option. And it displays priority and niceness by default. And ps should display all processes (if given the right arguments to select them) What system is this on?

Comment: well, macosx right now, but there is no difference between this and ubuntu at all... it does display them, but i need _only_ them and something else, not all possible stats.

Comment: Nothing wrong with questions about Mac OS X's Unix part here, AFAIK. Definitely different than Ubuntu though, as on Ubuntu `top -stats` gives an error about an unknown option.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this option exists only on osx... nothing about this on archlinux. Weird.  
So how can I manage fields that I want to display in `top` command on proper linux systems?

Comment: With Linux top, the only way I know is by writing a `~/.toprc` file (easily done by configuring it interactively how you'd like, then hitting `W`). I don't think top is really intended to be used by scripts.

Answer (score -2):

Use the latest utility `htop` instead of `top`.

Comment: How would `htop` help? It's just a curses version of `top`; he's using it from a script

Comment: htop is the advance package ... we can do multiple operations while running ...